# how to make one dictionary from several arrays. PYTHON

Tags: python, dictionary, arraylist

I want to make one dictionary out of several arrays in a loop

```
a = ["hello","hi"]
b = ["day","night"]
#And these arrays were transformed into a dictionary
c = {"a": "hello, hi", "b": "day, night"}
```

```
dictt = dict.fromkeys(a, b)
print(dictt)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a dictionary with the variable name as key, and the contents of the lists joined together as the values.

It is unusual to retrieve the variable names and use them as keys, so you could do it  manually like this:

```py
a = ["hello","hi"]
b = ["day","night"]

c = {
    'a': ', '.join(a),
    'b': ', '.join(b)
}

print(c) # {'a': 'hello, hi', 'b': 'day, night'}
```

If you want to loop over allot of a's and b's, I would organize the a and b differently. So you can loop over them. Like this:

```py
# here are your many lists
data = [
    ["hello","hi"],
    ["day","night"]
]

# here you go over all the lists and use the index as key
c = {}
for i, lst in enumerate(data):
    c[i] = ', '.join(lst)

print(c) # {0: 'hello, hi', 1: 'day, night'}
```

If you need the dictionary keys to be some string, you could use a list of keys alongside the data:

```py
# define keys
keys = ['a', 'b']

# here are your many lists
data = [
    ["hello","hi"],
    ["day","night"]
]

# here you go over all the lists and use the key for keys
c = {}
for i, lst in enumerate(data):
    c[keys[i]] = ', '.join(lst)

print(c) # {'a': 'hello, hi', 'b': 'day, night'}
```

If you want to avoid a list of keys but do want some letter as key. You could run through the alphabet for the keys. This is limited to the number of letters you can go over:

```py
# here are your many lists
data = [
    ["hello","hi"],
    ["day","night"]
]

# here you go over all the lists and use the alphabet letters in order as keys
c = {}
for i, lst in enumerate(data):
    c[chr(i+97)] = ', '.join(lst)

print(c) # {'a': 'hello, hi', 'b': 'day, night'}
```

Comment: An expression does not 'know' the name(s) that are bound to it as is implicit in the question. So, as shown by @Bas van der Linden it is inevitable these have to be listed or generated if they are to be used a dictionary keys.